# I can't create a reference link for my storage in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to firebase storage and at the same time create a reference for it in firebase database so I wrote this code in my js. It upload the file, but it can't create the reference in database. I keep trying different codes. It keep giving me the same result

```
let database=firebase.database();

storage=firebase.storage();

inpBild=document.getElementById("file");

bildeurler =database.ref("bildeuler");

largeUrl(snap){

    let url=snap.largeUrl;

    bildeurler.push(url);

}

function lastoppBild(){  

    let bilde=this.files[0];

    let bildenaven =storage.ref("bildeuler/"+ new Date());

    bildenaven.put(bilde).then(largeUrl);

    let bildeurler =database.ref("bildeuler");

}

inpBild.onchange=lastoppBild;
```

Comment: let url = snap.downloadURL; Please try this

Comment: i tried  this one too its still same is there any like specific storage rules in database rules

Comment: did you have included the storageBucket in your firebase config?

Comment: could u make ur answer more  clear please

Comment: lets make an example lets say we have this code for uploading file to storage and i want to create a link or a reference for it in firebase database what i should add 
var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
            fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('kora/'+file.name);
                  storageRef.put(file);
            });

Comment: what is the error that your getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
storage=firebase.storage().ref("bildeuler")
let bildenaven =storage.child(new Date());
```

[See firebase docs for storage ref creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#full_example)